# C - Segmentation Fault with dynamic allocations

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, fault, saddle

I'm doing this program to find the saddle point of a matrix (elements there are the greatest number on their column and at the same time the smallest on their row)

So, here is the thing, I'm getting a Segmentation Fault. When using windows, it works fine actually, but when I'm going to run on Ubunto, it doesn't work. I, unfortunitely, only have windows on my machine, so I can't figure out why it is not working or where it is going wrong.

Could you guys help me out? Tell me what is wrong with the code, or where is the error please!

```
int main(){
    int i, j, *ml, *mc, key = 1, z;
    int ordem, **me;
    char car;

    /* ml = smallest of each row, mc = greatest of each column
     * me = given matrix 
     * ordem = size of matrix */

    scanf("%d", &ordem);

    me = malloc(ordem * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < ordem; i++){
        me[i] = malloc(ordem * sizeof(int));
    }
    ml = malloc (ordem * sizeof(int));
    mc = malloc (ordem * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < ordem; i++){
        scanf("%d", &me[i][0]);
        for(j = 1; j < ordem; j++){
            scanf(" %d", &me[i][j]);
        }
        do{
            z = scanf("%c", &car);
        }while ((z != EOF) && (car != '\n'));
    }
```

If necessary, I can give you guys the rest of the code, but I'm quite sure that the error is happening in there, either on the malloc or the scanf.

Thanks a lot, really appreciate any help! Best regards!

Comment: I don't have `ubunto` either.

Comment: Hello there. Welcome to SO! Your question is probably going to be closed due to insufficient information. Please use a debugger to narrow the issue down to a particular line of code.

Comment: The first allocation should be `malloc(ordem * sizeof(int*))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int **me;
me = malloc(ordem * sizeof(int));
```

here is the mistake ! It's :

```
me = malloc(ordem * sizeof(int*));
```

Always double check your malloc, 90% of the segfault comme from here ...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably on the line

```
me = malloc(ordem * sizeof(int));
```

`me` is a `int**`, so you need to allocate for `int*`, not `int`.

This is giving you portability issues because different compilers do not necessarily use the same size for those data types.  Try running this code on the different machines to test what is going on.

```
printf("The size of an int  is %d\n", sizeof(int));
printf("The size of an int* is %d\n", sizeof(int*));
```

A way that you can modify your coding style so that this error is harder to make is to use the variable name in your sizeof like so

```
me = malloc(ordem * sizeof(*me));
```

This way you can visually see that you are allocating space for `ordem` variables of the type that `me` points to.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate the pointer array you need to take the element size of the pointer, not int. On your Ubuntu system the pointer size is probably 64 bit while ints are still 32, while on Windows both have the same size as was traditionally the case.

Comment: @Adarsh : the world doesn't end on x86.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar It's potentially wrong even there. His Ubuntu probably runs on some 64 bit derivate of x86.

Comment: Sorry @Peter updated his post later. Sorry about that.